# Halting program execution between certain hours of the week

Tags: java

I am writing a Java program that is required to copy files and folders between the following hours:

```
Mon - 18:00 to 06:30
Tue - 18:00 to 06:30
Wed - 18:00 to 06:30
Thu - 18:00 to 06:30
Fri - 18:00 to 06:30
Sat - all day
Sun - all day
```

The program will run **continuously** until it has finished copying all files and folders. However, outside of the above hours the program should just sleep.

I am using a properties file to store the above settings.

**UPDATE**

I am looking for the simplest possible implementation including the format of the properties in the properties file as well as the code that will make the checks.

Comment: would your program be running all the time and just 'work' at given time or you want program to start at particular time?

Comment: @ay89 I am running the program using a scheduled task on windows. Once started it will run for as many days as necessary to finish the transfer of files. And I am not transferring files to a network drive so can't use tools like robocopy.

Comment: Your program may simply read the properties file and call `Tread.sleep(..)` if the current time is in a not allowed time interval.

Answer (score 3):

I would do it like this

```
    final Map<Integer, String> schedule = new HashMap<>();
    // parse your settings and fill schedule
    schedule.put(Calendar.MONDAY, "18:00 to 06:30");
    // ...
    // create timer to fire e.g. every hour 
    new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            String s = schedule.get(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
            if (withinTimeRange(c, s)) { // implement withinTimeRange func
                // copy files
            }
        }}, 0, 1000 * 3600);
```

Comment: Thanks for that. However, I was looking to run the check after either a file has been copied. I just want it to stop if it tries to copy another doc but the time is outside of the allowed hours.

Comment: Cant see much difference, make a loop for each file to copy and check eahc time before you start copying next file, break as soon its outside range

Comment: Thank you for you answer. It wasn't quite what I was looking for. I want to check the schedule after performing each copy rather than scheduling copying at regular intervals. I have provided some of the code I implemented as an answer. You might be able to simplify it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since your program is going to run continuously, the simplest solution is to check the day and time before copying a file. If the time is during off hours, go ahead and copy the next file, otherwise `Thread.sleep`.

If this is an internal, one-off kind of program, I would go ahead and hard-code the business hours instead of reading the properties file. No need to add complexity.

Answer (score 1):

whenever your program is launched, get the current time, and check day today's day.

check whether it lies in permissible time if yes let it continue. If not, find the time at 00:00am of that 'day'. and find the time at xx:yyZZ (start of permissible time). calculate the difference, and let the program sleep for that much of time.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your suggestions.

I came up with a working solution in the end which if it gets enough points I will mark as the answer. The way I attempted to solve this problem was by thinking about non-working hours rather than working hours. This code is just for **illustration**

```
# Properties
Mon = 06:30-18:00
Tue = 06:30-18:00
Wed = 06:30-18:00
Thu = 06:30-18:00
Fri = 06:30-18:00
```

Loop over the properties to get their values

```
String[] days = { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" };

Map<Integer, Integer[]> nonWorkingHours = new HashMap<Integer, Integer[]>();
for( int i = 0; i < days.length; i++ ) // for each property in file
{
    // excluded implementation of getConfig
    String prop = getConfig( days[ i ] ); // e.g. "06:00-19:00"

    // +1  to match CALENDAR.DAY_OF_WEEK
    nonWorkingHours.put( i + 1, getHours( prop ); 
}
```

My function to parse property excluding error handling

```
// e.g. if prop = "06:00-19:00" then { 6, 0, 19, 0 } is returned
public Integer[] getHours( String prop )
{
    String times = prop.split( "(:|-)" );
    Integer[] t = new Integer[4];

    for( int i = 0; i < times.length; i++ )
    {
        t[i] = Integer.parseInt( times[i] );
    }
    return t;
}
```

And finally the function that implements the halt

```
private void sleepIfOutsideWorkingHours()
{
    Integer[] data = nonWorkingHours.get( currentDay );

    if( data != null )
    {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        Integer currentSeconds = ( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY * 3600 ) + ( Calendar.MINUTE * 60 );
        Integer stopFrom = ( data[ 0 ] * 3600 ) + ( data[ 1 ] * 60 );
        Integer stopTill = ( data[ 2 ] * 3600 ) + ( data[ 3 ] * 60 );

        if( currentSeconds > stopFrom && currentSeconds < stopTill )
        {
            Integer secondsDiff = stopTill - currentSeconds;

            if( secondsDiff > 0 )
            {
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep( secondsDiff * 1000 ); // turn seconds to milliseconds
                }
                catch( InterruptedException e )
                {
                    // error handling
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

And finally just call the function below just before copying each file and if it is being run outside working hours it will stop the program.

```
sleepIfOutsideWorkingHours();
```

I am sure there is a simpler way of doing it :-) but there it is.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using a Continuous Integration system. That scenario can be easily set up using [Jenkins CI](http://jenkins-ci.org/) for example.

The reason i advise doing it so in a ambient like that is that you can keep a better control on the history of your program runs.

Comment: Jenkins? For a scheduled java task?

Comment: Why not? I'm not saying this is the only possible scenario, but i have several scheduled tasks and automation runs stored in it. Keeps managing simple.